# jsx command not found on mac terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, reactjs

**Problem:**

- I execute the following command from the macintosh terminal:

  ```
  $ jsx --watch src/ build/
  ```
- I recieve the following output error from the terminal:

  ```
  -bash: jsx: command not found
  ```

**Relevant information:**

- I am following the following tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html
- I executed the following command from the tutorial with positive output:

  ```
  $ npm install -g react-tools
  ```
- This instruction immediately precedes the instruction that produces the error:

**Environment information:**

```
   $ node -v
    v0.12.4
   $ npm
    2.10.1
```

**Best of google:**

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/TUBkgptg2dM

**Adtional Notes:**

- Best of google is short because there aren't many links that provide information that the tutorial provides. A result of this is that I think there is an obvious solution and that I am just being dumb.
- I will provide more information if requested
- Please excuse the format of this question. This is how I solve a problem. I'm hoping someone can provide the **Solution** points. I apologize if this is over-the-top for a simple question, but I couldn't find any rules against it.

**Solution** to my unique problem:

- Execute the following command:

  ```
  $ export PATH=$PATH:$(npm config get prefix)/bin
  ```
- Original problem command:

  ```
  $ jsx --watch src/ build/
  ```
- New positive output:

  ```
  built Module("helloworld")
  ["helloworld"]
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run this:

```
npm config get prefix
```

that will give you a clue as to where your global npm modules are installed. you need to add the bin directory under the directory returned by the above to your path. for example, it might return /usr/local, in which case you should add /usr/local/bin to your PATH. You could just do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(npm config get prefix)/bin
```