# React command-line tools not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per React's "getting started" guide, I've downloaded the starter kit and attempted to also install React's command-line tools thus

```
npm install -g react-tools
```

. . . but, when I enter

```
jsx
```

into the command line, I receive an error message that reads "zsh: command not found: jsx." I've already restarted iTerm (I'm on a Mac) and have attempted to reinstall React's command-line tools several times but have had no luck.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30808203/1669277